# excel check for certain text and output value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to check for a certain piece of text in a cell and output its corresponding value.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T1 | 45 |  |
| 2 | T2 | 34 |  |
| 3 | R1 | 75 |  |
| 4 | R2 | 75 |  |

The idea is that in column `D` it outputs the value of `C` depending if `B` contains a "T" or an "R"

Later on, I want to calculate with these values.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your given conditions and the data sample in the OP, the following should work.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(B1)={"T","R"}),C1,"")
```

---

Using dynamic array formulas:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=MAP(B1:B4,C1:C4,LAMBDA(α,φ,IF(OR(LEFT(α)={"T","R"}),φ,"")))
```

---

Or by using <kbd>MMULT()</kbd> as mentioned by **[P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b)** Sir

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=MMULT((LEFT(B1:B4)={"T","R"})*C1:C4,{1;1})
```

---

Comment: to spill without using MAP: `=MMULT((LEFT(B1:B4)={"T","R"})*C1:C4,{1;1})`

Comment: @P.b Sir, thanks for the alternative just posted.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND(LEFT(B1:B4),"TR")),"",C1:C4)
```